# Excel Office Add-in Shows Blank after deploying

Tags: excel, office365, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

I have developed an Office Excel Add-in using yo generator, Angular in VS code. Add-in works fine locally. It shows up on the pane. However, after generating a build in dist folder, I happened to deploy this on the web server and calling this URL in the manifest.xml file, which is again inside a shared folder, to load it in Excel file. But this time around, I get a message in the add-in as "Please sideload your addin to see app body." after few seconds, the add-in shows a blank screen, without any errors.

Can you kindly let me know if there is a way to understand if there are any errors?

I have tried using IEChooser.exe (C:\Windows\System32\F12\IEChooser.exe) which shows open instances of IE. This shows all the console logs of the add-in application. But I cannot use this, as add-in goes blank even before IEChooser fires up.